# Highcharts column change color, but marker/dot not changing

Tags: highcharts

i'm create highchart column i'm change the color bar, but marker/dot not changing.

i want marker/dot same with color bar

Progress : Orange

Done : Green

Target : Blue

i don't know how to fix it, see this picture

[image]

See my demo [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wuqjod9/)

This is my code

```
$(function () {
              $('#sales').highcharts({
                  chart: {
                      type: 'column'
                  },
                  title: {
                      text: 'Performance Sales'
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                      categories: ['Yulia','UUM','Sinta']
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                      min: 0,
                      title: {
                          text: 'Values'
                      }
                  },
                   credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                  plotOptions: {
                      column: {
                          dataLabels: {
                              enabled: true,
                              formatter: function () {
                                  return this.point.custom;
                              }
                          },
                      },

                  },
                  series: [ 
                  {
                      name: 'Progress',
                      data: [
                             {
                              color:'orange',
                              custom:17,
                              y:16150000
                            },
                            {
                                color:'orange',
                                custom:4,
                                y:195449100
                             },
                            {
                              color:'orange',
                              custom:16,
                              y:128000000
                            }
                          ]
                  },
                  {
                      name: 'Done',
                      data: [
                        {
                           color:'#90ED7D',
                           custom:16,
                           y:9000000
                        },{
                          color:'#90ED7D',
                          custom:0,
                          y:0
                        },
                        {
                           color:'#90ED7D',
                           custom:8,
                           y:128000000
                        }                     
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      name: 'Target',
                      data: [
                        {
                          color:'#7CB5EC',
                          custom:'',
                          y:50000000
                        },
                        {
                          color:'#7CB5EC',
                          custom:'',
                          y:30000000
                        },
                        {
                            color:'#7CB5EC',
                            custom:'',
                            y:70000000
                        }                    
                        ]
                  }
                  ]
              });
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this color for the whole series, not only for particular points. Legend color is inherited from the series color.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vsud1nky/

```
series: [{
    color: 'orange',
    name: 'Progress',
    data: [{
        custom: 17,
        y: 16150000
      },
      {
        custom: 4,
        y: 195449100
      },
      {
        custom: 16,
        y: 128000000
      }
    ]
  }....
]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.color

Comment: just one color ?

Comment: Yeah, this one option sets the color for the whole series and the legend.